# Call method of named component after click on another

Tags: javascript, angular

I have users cards (or list). For users who have `status='err'` the error icon (`<tooltip-icon>`) should appear after user name (which is inside `<span>`). Tooltip first shows icon and  on click shows message (this works), but I also want to show this message when someone click on username.

```js
// typescript part:

showTooltip(tooltipMsg, user) {
  if(user.status=='err') {
    tooltipMsg.showMessage();  // here I have undefined
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="users-cards">
  <div *ngFor="let user of users" class="card"> 
    <span (click)="showTooltip(tooltip, user)">{{ user.name }}</span>
    <tooltip-icon 
      *ngIf="user.status=='err'" 
      [label]="user.msg" 
      #tooltip
    ></tooltip-icon>
  </div>           
</div>
```

The `<tooltip-icon>` has public method `showMessage()` and I want to call it when someone click on user name. The problem is that when I click on `<span>` then inside method `showTooltip` the `tooltipMsg==undefined` allways. So how to get access to `showMessage()` after click on `<span>`?

Answer (score 0):

When I do this

```html
    <tooltip-icon 
      [show]="user.status=='err'"
      [label]="user.msg" 
      #tooltip
    ></tooltip-icon>
```

and implement `show` @Input param inside tooltip-icon component - then it just works.

However this is only not efficient workaround (because we create extra nodes in DOM) - is there a way to not drop `*ngIf` ?